# What are the dance moves used by Mabuchi Kyōma in Dimension W's opening song (S1)?

Tags: dimension-w

What are the names of the dance moves used by Mabuchi Kyōma in the opening song of Season 1 of Dimension W?

[image: dance moves used by Mabuchi Kyōma in the opening song of Dimension W]

You can see a bigger version of the png at this  [link](http://giphy.com/gifs/mabuchi-kyma-dance-moves-in-dimension-w-xThuWvxpHQH7Zaadws)

Comment: My friend Chad recognized one of them as the indian step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dancing is a form of art where one expresses them self so not all dance move are going to be identical.

The links for each move are examples how each dance.

The first move is called [Top Rocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toprock).

[image]

The second move is a variation of the [Indian Step](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDwSu2nfSXw).

[image]

The third move seems to be similar to the finger snapping in [West Side Story](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2ClSABkDp8).

[image]

The fourth move is a variation of a [Kick Cross](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHGYYAuaZ4U).

[image]